# Xcode template <<date>> format

Tags: xcode, templates, xcode-template

I'm working up a custom Xcode template, and I'd like to change the way `<<date>>` is formatted.

For example:

```
//  Created by «FULLUSERNAME» on «DATE».
//  Copyright «YEAR» «ORGANIZATIONNAME». All rights reserved.
```

if the file was created today would fill as:

```
//  Created by SooDesuNe on 2/24/2010.
//  Copyright 2010 MyOrganization. All rights reserved.
```

Dates formatted in any "all numbers" format can cause a lot of confusion, since the ISO and JIS way of writing the same date is 24/2/2010.  It's clear on the 24th day of the month, but not so clear on the first 12 days of the month.

I would like x-code to populate `<<date>>` like:

```
//  Created by SooDesuNe on 24-Feb-2010.
//  Copyright 2010 MyOrganization. All rights reserved.
```

Since there is no ambiguity that way.  Anyone know how to change the date format?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.xcode AppleICUDateFormatStrings '{ 1 = "d-MMM-y"; }'
```

Comment: Copied that into the terminal, and created a new file from my template.  But the date formate was still mm/dd/yy

Comment: That got it, thanks!

Where is that type of information documented?

Comment: It isn't.  The date formats are from ICU, which OS X has used for a while; I just configured the format for myself in Date & Time System Preferences then did a 'defaults read -g' to see where it was written. Global defaults with a particular key are shadowed by the corresponding application defaults, which allows this to work.

Comment: Not working on Xcode 9, even after a full system restart

Comment: Xcode's bundle identifier has changed, so `com.apple.xcode` won't work any more; use `com.apple.dt.Xcode`. In general there is a new much more flexible system for file templates in Xcode 9; see for more information: https://oleb.net/blog/2017/07/xcode-9-text-macros/ (unfortunately all you get is a date or year though; you can't specify a date format inline from what I am aware). Also note that custom date formats have migrated into Language & Region Preferences under the Advanced… button.

Answer (score 7):

You can just change your short format of your time displaying in system preferences., then restart xcode, the default date format will be changed

Comment: From my observation it looks like Xcode's settings in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Xcode.plist` are overridden by system's time and date settings, so your solution worked for me after restarting Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show the default Date and User name you can add these two lines in your `___FILEBASENAME___.swift` file

```
// ___FILEBASENAMEASIDENTIFIER___
// Created by ___FULLUSERNAME___ on ___DATE___.
```

This will show the File name and created by the User and Current date.

However if you want to add the header you can add the below line

```
//___FILEHEADER___
```

Result will be:-

```
//
//  TestViewController.swift
//  MyProjectName
//
//  Created by Rashid on 28/12/2021.
//
```